# MySQL - F5 needed to "see" the new row generated previously

Tags: caching, https

eHello, everyone.

Well, here goes my problem. I don't know which code to share given this type of issue so I'll be as detailed as I can.

Many years ago I crafted a common admin for a publisher's website. It has always worked perfectly UNTIL NOW.

Action: user "A" creates an edition with the add.php file, sends it to process.php, saves a normal row in the database (verified, item saved successfully), and kicks the user to index.php where an HTML table is shown with all the items that are in the related MySQL table.

Problem: when user "A" reaches index.php forwarded by the save itself, he sees the table (the HTML one formed by PHP according to what there is in the base) WITHOUT SHOWING THE NEW ITEM. Only after hitting F5, it shows the last row entered.

The problem continues: if any user "B" let's say, goes to the index, then leaves (either out the index or the whole site) and returns at a later time after user "A" loaded the new item HE DOESN'T SEE THE ITEM EITHER unless he ALSO hits F5! (with different computers, I mean)

It looks like some cache is bothering or at least that's the impression it gives me. I've put all the no-caches I could think of but it keeps happening.

IMPORTANT: everything was perfect until the company bought a certificate for HTTPS. I throw in this data in case it may have to do with or is just a coincidence. We made a replica of ALL THE ADMIN in a subdomain of the same domain with the certificate and THE REPLICA WORKS WELL! (There are hundreds of dependencies and routes to them and using the mirror is practically unfeasible due to all the recoding of routes and backup that would have to be done)

Can anyone offer any ideas on where I should hit with the hammer to get it working properly again? The admin is used by several editors and there is a great margin of error in they having to hit F5 before making new editions to avoid, for example, that they duplicate things because the system is showing them a "memory" from when that item didn't exist yet.

Thank you very much!

(English is not my main language, sorry if some words or ideas don't convey so well)

Comment: This is extremely difficult to answer objectively as you are basically asking for tips what to debug.

Comment: I know. I'm out of ideas even on what or how to ask. I hope someone experienced the same issue and could tell me something about it...